# how to use this.sample() - instead of this.cursor.getInt()

Tags: java, android

```
final String query = "SELECT " +
                "questiontable.QuestionID, questiontable.answer0, questiontable.answer1, questiontable.answer2, questiontable.answer3, questiontable.answer4, questiontable.Correct, " +
                " FROM questiontable" +

                " WHERE questiontable.QuestionID IN ( " +
                allQuestionIds +
                " )  ORDER BY questiontable.QuestionID ";
        this.cursor = this.db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (this.cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                for (final Question q : questions) {
                    if (q.getQuestionId() == this.cursor.getInt(0)) {
                        q.addAnswer(new Answer(this.cursor.getString(1),
                                this.cursor.getString(2),
                                this.cursor.getString(3),
                                this.cursor.getString(4),
                                this.cursor.getString(5),
                                (this.cursor.getInt(6) == 1 ? true : false)));
                    }
                }
            } while (this.cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        this.cursor.close();
```

I want to add **this.sample()** like:

```
             q.addAnswer(new Answer(this.sample(),
                                    this.cursor.getString(1),
                                    this.cursor.getString(2),
                                    this.cursor.getString(3),
                                    this.cursor.getString(4),
                                    this.cursor.getString(5),
                                    (this.cursor.getInt(6) == 1 ? true : false)));
```

**what I want to do:**

*Create a sample() method that will take my integer values (AnswerID)

*AnswerID will be an integer value that takes integer value of QuestionID (this.cursor.getInt(0)) and near it; a number from 0 to 4.  So, for each QuestionID I will have 5 values (10,11,12,13,14 - 20,21,22,23,24 - ......)

*Use this.sample()

*My code  what I imagine ( it may be fully wrong )*

```
 void sample (int AnswerID) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                                 AnswerID = this.cursor.getInt(0) + i ;
                            }
                        this.sample = sample;   

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, because your method is void.
Void - doesn't return anything.

```
void sample (int AnswerID) {
..
}
```

If you want to calculate something you could try to create the method that returns
 an arrayList of integers and pass it as params to the  q.addAnswer method.

```
public  ArrayList<Integer>  sample(Cursor cur) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(cur.getInt(0));//first test case
    ...
    //numbers is array list of integers
    return numbers;
}
```

So you can work with arrayList of integers.

Comment: Really thanks for answer. I'm new to java and confused about rest of codes.  **numbers.add(cur.getInt(0));** adds QuestionID Ithink. so Ineed to use : numbers.add(cur.getInt(0)+0); numbers.add(cur.getInt(0)+1); numbers.add(cur.getInt(0)+2); .... Then **this.sample() = numbers;**  After that I will be able to use this.sample() in q.addAnswer method. Am I right ?

Comment: I also want to ask how to apply my array list into void
Will cur.getInt(0) work out of my void method ?

Comment: @santral call it like this this.sample(this.cursor) for my method.

Comment: thanks for your  replies. but I think I need int values instead of arraylist.   I was getting answerid values from database ( answerid ) with **this.cursor.getInt()** . Now I want to make my own automatic answer ids' (int) . and put it  instead of his.cursor.getInt(). I'm confused alittle to do that!

Comment: @santral it's better to use Array list of integer than the simple array of integers in your case.